# Relation between batch size, number of steps, and learning rate

Tags: machine-learning, training, hyperparameter-tuning, hyperparameter, mini-batch-gradient-descent

Taking alphazero training setup as a reference:

```
700k total steps
batch-size of 4096
initial LR of 0.2
```

What would be an equivalent setup for a batch-size of 1024? Is it:

```
4x700k=2.8m steps
batch-size=1024
initial LR of 0.2/4=0.05
```

Here I am assuming same number of epochs for equivalent results, but maybe same number of steps (back-propagation steps) give equivalent results instead. So maybe:

```
700k steps
batch-size=1024
initial LR=0.05
```